# Getting the error message ServletActionRedirectResult incompatible with ServletDispatcherResult

Tags: java, struts2, upgrade, dispatcher, actionresult

I have upgraded my Struts 2.0 application to Struts 2.3.15.2. The application is working fine. But I see few messages in system out log.

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error Exception occurred 
  during processing request: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult 
  incompatible with org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult
```

What causes this error?

Comment: If you're redirecting during the execution of an action's code, are you then returning from the method? I know in Struts 1 you get warning/error messages if you redirect, then try to return a forward, from the same action.

Comment: share your pom or set of libraries you're using ?

Comment: Yeah, I do redirect during the execution of an action'scode and then returning from the method. In Java class, I have included the code dispatcherResult = (ServletDispatcherResult) invocation.getResult(); where I am getting the exception

Comment: Here is my sample code in XML                                            <action name="brokerlogin" class="LoginAction"
method="login">
<result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
<result name="STATEMENT" type="redirect">searchStmtAll
</result>
<result name="recentActivityConfirm" type="redirectAction">
<param name="actionName">recentActivityConfirm</param>
<param name="mostRecentFlag">Y</param>
</result>
<interceptor-ref name="brokerDefaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="usertrackinglogin">
<param name="includeMethods">login</param>
</interceptor-ref>
</action>

Comment: @Prashanth Do not add information in comments; edit it into the question. It's completely illegible here.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration you didn't use result type `dispatcher` which is a default result type. The instance of `ServletActionRedirectResult` is returned from action invocation. If you want to get a type of the result you could check that instance

```
Result result = invocation.getResult();
if (result instanceof ServletDispatcherResult){
  ServletDispatcherResult dispatcherResult = (ServletDispatcherResult )result;
  ...
}
```